# The environment variable declared in setenv.sh is not setting

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I am working with tomcat 7 on aws linux AMI. I have installed the tomcat 7 and its working fine. Now I need to deploy the [eHour](https://ehour.nl/) webapp in it. I have followed all the procedure given  in this [documentation](https://wiki.ehour.nl/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6324226).But when I run the ehour app it does not start and following error is thrown.

*Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${EHOUR_HOME}/conf/ehour.properties (No such file or directory)*

also when I do printenv there is no EHOUR_HOME variable in the list.Below is my code for setenv.sh

```
    # Load Tomcat Native Library
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/bitnami/common/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    EHOUR_HOME=/home/bitnami/ehour
    JAVA_HOME=/opt/bitnami/java
    JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
    JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseG1GC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  $JAVA_OPTS "
  . "/opt/bitnami/java/bitnami/setenv.sh"
     export JAVA_HOME
     export JRE_HOME
     export JAVA_OPTS
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
     export EHOUR_HOME
```

If you can please point out my mistake or some other way to declare EHOUR_HOME variable so that tomcat can pick it during its startup.
Thanks

Comment: can you confirm you restarted tomcat after you made any changes to `sentenv` script ?

Comment: Yes I did reboot the instance as well as tomcat.