# deploy eHour in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, war

I need your help because I try to install [eHour](https://ehour.nl/) on my server (it is a windows server) without success:

as described in the [documentation](https://wiki.ehour.nl/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=393222), there  are two types of installations:

- Standalone
- War file (documentation link seems bad and go to old installation instructions, new is [here](https://wiki.ehour.nl/display/DOCU/Install+WAR+on+Tomcat) )

First, I try Standalone way but even if eHour service was running, I didn't have any web pages.
So I uninstall eHour and try to use the War file way

as it is a new server, I install Apache Tomcat (version 10.0.4) and mysql
Then, I copy WAR distribution and I unzip it to my C drive (I also renamed the folder from ehour-1.4.3 to ehour)
Then I create a setevn.bat file and create a variable EHOUR_HOME
`set EHOUR_HOME="c:\ehour"`

Then I download mysql connector and copy file mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar to Tomcat 10.0/lib directory

Finally, I rename the war file from ehour-1.4.3.war to ehour.war and copy it to Tomcat 10.0/webapps directory

I start apache and a directory ehour has been added to Tomcat 10.0/webapps directory
but localhost:8080/ehour result is 404 : The requested resource [/ehour] is not available.

I look in catalina log but see nothing that help me

Any tips ?

it seems I do have same error than [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911458/the-environment-variable-declared-in-setenv-sh-is-not-setting) :
in file localhost.log I do have similar error:

```
EHOUR_HOME environment variable or context parameter not defined   
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${EHOUR_HOME}\conf\ehour.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Howerver, I do create a file setenv.bat in Tomcat/bin directory
its contents is :
`set EHOUR_HOME="c:\ehour"`
something I miss?

Comment: Tomcat 10 implements Servlet 5.0, which is incompatible with most web applications. Check [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64387472/11748454). You should use Tomcat 9.0 instead.

Comment: it doesn't help but I do have some error in logs : INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

Comment: You should add the logs by editing your question, not in a comment. The _"appropriate container log file"_ is `catalina.<date>.log`.

Comment: Check also `localhost. <date>.log` for the details of the errors.

Comment: ok, I found new log in localhost.<date>.log file : seems ehour variable is not well set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Windows, so you are probably using [Procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) (Commons Daemon/Tomcat Monitor) to start Tomcat as a Windows service. Procrun doesn't use the `*.bat` files at all, everything is configured through the graphical interface `prunmgr` (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21885863/11748454) for screenshots).

Unfortunately you can't configure environment variables through the graphical interface, so either:

- add the environment variable **globally** (for all users) to your system,
- or add the environment variable to **procrun** either:

  - run

    ```
    Tomcat10.exe update "++Environment=C:\ehour"
    ```

    (`Tomcat10.exe` is a copy of procrun and is in the `bin` directory of Tomcat's installation),
  - add to the windows registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<service_name>\Parameters` a new value named `Environment` of type `REG_MULTI_SZ` with data `EHOUR_HOME=C:\ehour`.

**Edit:** There are actually three different sources for the `EHOUR_HOME` configuration parameter (cf. [`EhourHomeUtil`](https://github.com/te-con/ehour/blob/4e922be3e52caaf3fb8d89945cc163166e2bac7a/eHour-common/src/main/java/net/rrm/ehour/appconfig/EhourHomeUtil.java#L23) and [`EnvInitListener`](https://github.com/te-con/ehour/blob/4e922be3e52caaf3fb8d89945cc163166e2bac7a/eHour-wicketweb/src/main/java/net/rrm/ehour/ui/listener/EnvInitListener.java#L19)), which are looked up in this order:

1. the Java system property `EHOUR_HOME`, which you can configure in e.g. `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties`,
2. the OS environment variable `EHOUR_HOME`, configured as explained above,
3. the servlet context init parameter `EHOUR_HOME`, which can be configured in the [appropriate context file](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context):

```xml
<Parameter name="EHOUR_HOME" value="/path/to/ehour" />
```

Comment: perfect! I create a windows registry key . Note that data shall be ```EHOUR_HOME=C:/ehour```  however it is reading as C:ehour

Comment: `EHOUR_HOME=C:\ehour` will set the value of `EHOUR_HOME` to `C:\ehour`, but the program itself may choke on the quirks of Windows file path syntax. Java interprets `C:/ehour` and `/C:/ehour` as a synonim for `C:\ehour`.