# deploy eHour in Apache Tomcat (war file deployed but not started) - possible environment variable issue

Tags: tomcat, war

I need your help because I try to install eHour on my server (it is a windows server) without success:

as described in the documentation, there are two types of installations, but I'm trying to deploy War file.

I install Apache Tomcat (9.0.52) and mysql Then, I copy WAR distribution and I unzip it to my C drive (I also renamed the folder from ehour-1.4.3 to ehour)
Then I create a `setevn.bat` file and create a variable `EHOUR_HOME`
set `EHOUR_HOME="c:\ehour"`

Then I download mysql connector and copy file mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar to Tomcat 10.0/lib directory

Finally, I renamed the war file from ehour-1.4.3.war to ehour.war and copy it to Tomcat 9.0/webapps directory

I start apache and a directory ehour has been added to Tomcat 9.0/webapps directory but localhost:8080/ehour result is 404 : The requested resource [/ehour] is not available.

exception is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${EHOUR_HOME}\conf\ehour.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have defined environment variable `EHOUR_HOME` and also registry key and if I type set I can see `EHOUR_HOME` is defined as `C:\ehour` but it doesn't work....

Can anyone help?
I saw [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66674559/11748454) some months ago asked by DonKnacki but I don't know whether it worked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I update the answer to the question you cite. Can you check all possibilities to set the `EHOUR_HOME` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

It worked adding to the windows registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0<service_name>\Parameters a new value named Environment of type REG_MULTI_SZ with data EHOUR_HOME=C:\ehour